# create explicit intent from scratch without creating an ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, android-intent

i am still struggling to open up my app to the external world.
At first i let everything be handled by MainActivity, but i have 2 cases (add + del) where a headless mode is better/faster/no flicker etc...

So i made a second entry into my app Manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".IntStringSynchro"
        android:label="@string/headless" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ADD" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.EMBED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and reading here on Stackoverflow, i first tested it internally, so i added to my main activity a button that starts an intent to call on this activity...

so somewhere in onClick:

```
else if (p1 == testBut)
{
   String tstpathToProject = "AppProjects/IntStringIntentTester/app/src/main/res";

  Intent callIt = new Intent(this, IntStringSynchro.class);
  callIt.addCategory("android.intent.category.EMBED");
  callIt.setAction("ADD");
  callIt.putExtra("token", "testtoto");
  callIt.putExtra("value", "titi");
  callIt.putExtra("value-de", "tata");
  callIt.setAction("ADD");
  callIt.putExtra("path", tstpathToProject);//relative
  Log.d(TAG, "sending intent " + callIt + " " + callIt.getExtras());

  try
  {
    startActivityForResult(callIt, ASK_STRINGMOD);
  }
  catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
  {
    Toast.makeText(this, "no available activity " + callIt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

that worked as avertised, but this won't work, when another app tries to build that intent, since it won't have access to the class files of my app, so i changed the relevant part to

```
  Intent callIt = new Intent();
  callIt.setClassName("com.nohkumado.intstringsynchro", "IntStringSynchro");
  callIt.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.nohkumado.intstringsynchro", "IntStringSynchro"));
  callIt.addCategory("android.intent.category.EMBED");
  callIt.setAction("ADD");
 etc.
```

but this now yields an activity not found exception...

i am a bit confused, since there doesn't seem to be a method to set the context, that is present on the local intent call i made before...
the component part is to replace the explicit class instance given in the first type constructor, the setClassName, doubles the setComponent, not, is useless?

since neither work, i am missing something somewhere, but what?
as sayd, the thing is, i want to make this intent call then from another app...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change the second  parameter of `setComponentName` constructor

```
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.package.address","com.package.address.UrActivity"));
```

Comment: ok adapted it to callIt.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.nohkumado.intstringsynchro","com.nohkumado.intstringsynchro.IntStringSynchro"));
      and it works, but why? it seems a bit redundant to give the package name again?

Comment: Full package name is needed to call Activity class ; cud have take that from the first parameter, but hey ....  must admit not neat... but it does the job ;-)

Comment: indeed, but this should definitely be something written in the official API docu.... maybe one of those undocumented "features" anyway thanks a lot, the whole thing now works flawlessly, a greate relief